# How to set up web server in c# console application

Tags: c#, exception, webserver, console-application, port

Here is the code, problems listed below:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace BasicWebServer
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            var port = 1043;
            var serverListener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, port);

            serverListener.Start();

            Console.WriteLine($"Server started on port {port}.");
            Console.WriteLine("Listening for requests...");

            while (true)
            {    var connection = serverListener.AcceptTcpClient();

                var networkStream = connection.GetStream();

                var content = "Hello World!";

                var contentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(content);

                var response = $@"HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain;
charset=UTF-8
Content-Length:{contentLength}
{content}";

                var responseBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);

                networkStream.Write(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);

                connection.Close();
            }

        }
        
    }
}
```

It is supposted to listen to incoming connections to that port and display the data. The first error that I get is:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'An attempt was made to access a
> socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions'

I tried looking into command prompt to see what ports are excluded and it wasn't on that list. The command that I used is

> netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp

Then I checked if I can connect to it in PowerShell via this command

> Test-NetConnection -ComputerName localhost -Port 1043

the result was this

- ComputerName     : localhost
- RemoteAddress    : ::1
- RemotePort       : 1043
- InterfaceAlias   : Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
- SourceAddress    : ::1
- TcpTestSucceeded : True

I also tried disabling my firewall to see if it has blocked that port but found nothing.

**So how can I check what ports I can use without getting this error?**

**The second error that I encountered was** [image]

Comment: You are closing the connection inside the while loop.  The code works the first time through loop.  The second time through while loop serverListener is null (because connection was closed) which give error.  Close connection is also closing the serverListener.

Comment: I moved the things to a different class and rearranged everything. It works now, I can post the new code if it would help someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the updated code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BasicWebServer.Server
{
    public class HttpServer
    {
        private readonly IPAddress ipAddress;
        private readonly int port;
        private readonly TcpListener serverListenter;

        public HttpServer(string ipAddress, int port)
        {
            this.ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);
            this.port = port;

            this.serverListenter = new TcpListener(this.ipAddress, port);
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Server started on port {port}.");
            Console.WriteLine("Listening for requests...");

            while (true)
            {
                this.serverListenter.Start();

                var connection = serverListenter.AcceptTcpClient();

                var networkStream = connection.GetStream();

                WriteResponse(networkStream, "Hello there!");

                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        private void WriteResponse(NetworkStream networkStream, string message)
        {
            var contentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(message);

            var response = $@"HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: {contentLength}

{message}";
            var responseBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);

            networkStream.Write(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).